# HTML + CSS - Centering Images With Hyperlinks

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, visual-glitch

So I have two images with hyperlinks and when I try to center them, they act funny so I thought huh, maybe the dimensions of the elements are... distorted? Somehow? So I add a border around the elements and sure enough, the sizes of them look like this:

https://gyazo.com/f5a91e1a26eaf3aea6208ffa2eea698c

HTML:

```
<a id="home-invite-button" href="https://url.com" target="_blank"><img 
src="Images/Invite Button.png"></a>
<a id="home-wiki-button" href="https://url.com" target="_blank"><img 
src="Images/Wiki Button.png"></a>
```

CSS:

```
#home-invite-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 540px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: thin black solid;
}

#home-wiki-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 630px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: thin black solid;
}
```

So the question is, how can I make the actual size of the elements the same as the actual image? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid assigning the width to your images, instead wrap the `<a>` tags inside a div `content-holder` and then apply the positioning to the holder. The images will remain intact.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.content-holder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: thin black solid;
}

#home-invite-button {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#home-wiki-button {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-holder">
  <a id="home-invite-button" href="https://url.com" target="_blank"><img 
  src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
  <a id="home-wiki-button" href="https://url.com" target="_blank"><img 
  src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! I also learned that the width thing isn't actually the way to go. Overall, great answer :)

Comment: It's my pleasure. Please also upvote it, if you find this answer useful.

Comment: hehe yeah I need 15 rep first :P

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
a img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

if You also see this Link: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sayed021/tpnoztx6/)

Comment: I've tried this just now and it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: When Center your link then Sure your Links Wrapper example: https://jsfiddle.net/sayed021/tpnoztx6/1/